# Recursively grep only directories matching a pattern?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to figure out how to speed up a recursive grep by searching only files in sub dirs that match a string.

Example:

```
/foo/bar/baz/mylogs/somelog.log
/foo/bar/notme.log
/cat/dog/mylogs/anotherlog.log
```

I need to grep only the `*.log` files under `*/mylogs/*`

I can find all log files with the following...

```
egrep -h -R --include \*.log '(pattherns|to|match)'
```

but this doesn't ...

```
egrep -h -R --include \/mylogs/\*.log '(pattherns|to|match)'
```

How can I narrow down the include path?

Comment: Are there subdirectories in `mylogs`, and should they be searched as well?

Comment: No, no subdirs in mylogs, just files ending in .log

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `find` to locate any directories matching that name and utilizing its `exec` flag to run `egrep` on what it finds. The following example recursively `egrep`s through the matching directories for the pattern 'foo':

```
find . -type d -name mylogs -exec egrep -hR --include=\*.log foo {} +
```

The `+` suffix means `find` will feed as many results to a single `egrep` process as it can.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` has a `--exclude-dir` option, but no `--include-dir` option. The `--include` option only allows you to match filename, not filepath

If you are using newer versions of `bash` shell or other shells that support `extglob`, you can also do this:

```sh
$ shopt -s extglob 
$ # mylogs without sub-dirs
$ ls **/mylogs/*.log
cat/dog/mylogs/anotherlog.log  foo/bar/baz/mylogs/somelog.log

$ # if mylogs can have sub-dirs as well
$ ls **/mylogs/**/*.log
a/b/mylogs/c/d/f.log  cat/dog/mylogs/anotherlog.log  foo/bar/baz/mylogs/somelog.log
```

once you are satisfied the files are matching as needed, use `grep` with that `glob`

```sh
grep -h '(pattherns|to|match)' **/mylogs/*.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use any GNU grep option to find files as they're completely unnecessary and just clutter up your calls to grep with a mush of file search options and actual g/re/p options. Keep it simple and use `find` to **find** files and `grep` to **g/re/p** within files:

```
find . -type d -name mylogs -print0 |
xargs -0 -I XX find XX -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.log' -exec grep -h 'foo' {} +
```

or you could even just do this if your file names don't contain newlines:

```
find . -type f -name '*.log' | grep '/mylogs/' | xargs grep -h 'foo'
```